# SQL how to take out data while looping through columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, calculated-columns

I have another issue with my SQL code. Below I will tell you by showing one of my tables and how I would like to take information out of it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqWs6.jpg]

1) All employees at a company belong to a department. In this table, for an example, employees 00010-00013 to Dept1 and 00019-00022 to Dept4.

2) When being paid, the table functions as a record wheter or not the employee has been paid with status "Paid" or "Unpaid" in the column Employee Status. As you can see, all employees except 00017 and 00022 have been paid.

3) When all employees belonging to a certain department have been paid, the Department Status should change to "Paid", meaning that all employees belonging to that department have been paid. As you can see all employees at Dept1 have been paid, and the Department Status is set to "Paid". All the employees at Dept4 have not been paid, and the Department Status is set to "Unpaid".

4) As you can see, there is an "error" made in Department Status of Dept2. Although all employees have been paid, the Department Status is still set to "Unpaid".

I need to construct a code that brings out all the departments like Dept2, that have all the Employees paid, but still haven't changed its status.

This could be made by either omitting all other (correct) departments, or maybe adding a new column in which this is noted so I can sort afterwards. Below I'll add som useless pseudocode that kind of shows what I want to achieve by adding a new column INCOR_DEP_STAT in which I tell if the Department Status is incorrect or not.

```
SELECT A.DEPART, A.DEPART_STAT, A.EMPLOY, A.EMPLOY_STAT, 'N/A' as INCOR_DEP_STAT
FROM PAYTABLE A

FOR all objects in A.DEPART;
  IF all A.EMPLOY_STAT in A.DEPART == "Paid" AND IF A.DEPART_STAT == "Unpaid"
   THEN INCOR_DEPT_STAT = "Incorrect"
```

Comment: Only tag products involved, to get the correct attention. Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL was an innocent typo! My bad.

Comment: In general, you should only *store* data that you can't *calculate* (or if you "must" store it for performance reasons, prefer to have SQL Server automatically maintain it via a computed column or indexed view). Why *store* the `DepartmentStatus` if it can always be calculated from the `EmployeeStatus`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it cannot always be calculated. If one EmployeeStatus is "Unpaid" then DepartmentStatus should always be "Unpaid". If one EmployeeStatus is "Paid" it doesn't say how many others in the Department that have been paid and you cannot define DepartmentStatus.

Comment: It sounds like it can be calculated - `DepartmentStatus` is `Paid` if all `EmployeeStatus` values (for that department) are `Paid`, otherwise its `Unpaid`. That's a fairly straightforward calculation. Or have I missed something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM PAYTABLE A
WHERE DEPART NOT IN (
   SELECT
      DEPART 
   FROM PAYTABLE A
   WHERE EMPLOY_STAT='Unpaid'
)
AND DEPART_STAT='Unpaid'
```

Comment: This worked! Amazing. Now I just need to go through it to understand it and make sure it doesn't omit any cases. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this way too complex.  To identify departments marked as Unpaid with employees marked as paid:

```
select
distinct department
from
PayTable
where
depart_stat= 'Unpaid'
and employ_stat= 'Paid'
```

If you want to derive a column to show this:

```
select
...,
case when depart_stat= 'Unpaid' and employ_stat = 'Paid' then 'Incorrect'
else 'Correct' end as Incor_Dept_Stat
from
PayTable
```

EDIT:
RE-read your question.  If you only want departments where the department status does not equal the employee status for all employees in that group:

```
select
dept,
dept_status
from
(
select
dept,
dept_status,
count (employee) as Emps,
count (case when Employ_Status <> Dept_Status then 1 else null end) as PaidStatus
from
PayTable
group by 
dept,
dept_status
) t
where
emps = PaidStatus
```

Comment: that "left justify" style of formatting your code is extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.DEPART_STAT
    , A.EMPLOY
    , A.EMPLOY_STAT
    , 'N/A' as INCOR_DEP_STAT
FROM PAYTABLE A
WHERE 'Paid' = ALL
    (SELECT p1.Status 
     FROM PAYTABLE p1  
     WHERE A.Department = P1.Department)
AND A.Status = 'UnPaid'
```